# How to view the terminal log when executing a remote Apache Pig script

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, apache-pig

I have written a script in Apache Pig which is being executed on a Hadoop cluster. It loads ~55 thousand of .gz files and takes 35 hours to complete. It should then store the results in a file, but it didn't, so I want to debug what happened.

I execute the script by typing:

```
pig script.pig
```

In the terminal of the Ubuntu virtual machine I see information messages about the progress of the job and so on. How can I view these messages even when shutting down my local machine? Do I really need to keep my local machine running for the full 35 hours just to see these messages?

I know you can type a command in Ubuntu and store the response by typing:

```
command > logfile.txt
```

But I think this won't work here, since the connection between the hadoop hdfs system and the virtual machine is lost during shutting down the local machine, so the log messages must be stored on the hadoop cluster. But how to achieve this, or is this done automatically and I simply don't know where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run from your local machine like that if the process gets killed (e.g. by shutting down your machine) then hadoop will kill the job. That's why you'd normally want to start long running jobs from a machine in the cluster or some portal node that runs 24/7.

If it is available to you, you can also use something like Oozie to run your job, then the Oozie server will take care of running the job and will provide the logs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I don't think I can run the job from a machine in the cluster, I just kept my local computer on for 40 hours which also worked.